# spring redis running script : how to pass expiry time value

Tags: spring-boot, lua, redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis

I use the lua script:

```
local lock = redis.call('get', KEYS[1])
if not lock then    
    return redis.call('SETEX', KEYS[1], ARGV[1] ,ARGV[2] );
end
return false
```

From spring boot application I use to call redis with the script

```
DefaultRedisScript<Boolean> redisScript = new
DefaultRedisScript<Boolean>();
redisScript.setScriptSource(new ResourceScriptSource(new ClassPathResource("checkandset2.lua")));
redisScript.setResultType(Boolean.class);
System.out.println(redisTemplate.execute(redisScript , Collections.singletonList("value123"),"10" ,"key123"));
```

I always get exception :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer.serialize(StringRedisSerializer.java:32)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.script.DefaultScriptExecutor.keysAndArgs(DefaultScriptExecutor.java:116)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.script.DefaultScriptExecutor$1.doInRedis(DefaultScriptExecutor.java:63)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:202)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:164)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:152)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.script.DefaultScriptExecutor.execute(DefaultScriptExecutor.java:60)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.script.DefaultScriptExecutor.execute(DefaultScriptExecutor.java:54)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:298)
at com.masary.ledger.ResisScriptTestClass.msisdnJustRechargedException(ResisScriptTestClass.java:34)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

When I use

> System.out.println(redisTemplate.execute(redisScript ,
>   Collections.singletonList("value123"),new Long(10) ,"key123"));

I get exception

```
     org.springframework.data.redis.RedisSystemException: Unknown redis exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
        at org.springframework.data.redis.FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.getFallback(FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:48)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:38)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.convertJedisAccessException(JedisConnection.java:212)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.evalSha(JedisConnection.java:3173)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.evalSha(JedisConnection.java:3158)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.DefaultStringRedisConnection.evalSha(DefaultStringRedisConnection.java:1374)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.core.CloseSuppressingInvocationHandler.invoke(CloseSuppressingInvocationHandler.java:57)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy182.evalSha(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.core.script.DefaultScriptExecutor.eval(DefaultScriptExecutor.java:81)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.core.script.DefaultScriptExecutor$1.doInRedis(DefaultScriptExecutor.java:71)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:202)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:164)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:152)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.core.script.DefaultScriptExecutor.execute(DefaultScriptExecutor.java:60)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.core.script.DefaultScriptExecutor.execute(DefaultScriptExecutor.java:54)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:298)
        at com.masary.ledger.ResisScriptTestClass.msisdnJustRechargedException(ResisScriptTestClass.java:34)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
.
.
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisScriptReturnConverter.convert(JedisScriptReturnConverter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.evalSha(JedisConnection.java:3171)
        ... 46 more
```

any advice how can I pass expiry time value to the lua script?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a newbie myself, and was having a similar problem. Try sending the string `"10"`, instead of the `Long`. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The thread might be old, but might be helpful for others who might stumble upon this.

For me, the reason was using `JdkSerializationRedisSerializer` as value serializer, like: `redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer())`, this is also the default.

To fix this, see below the fix:

```java
private static void redisEvalForExpire(String scriptText, List<String> keys, Object[] argv) {
  // since spring boot serializes data to - "\xac\xed\x00\x05t\x00\x0" it was not being recognized by redis as integer
  redisTemplate.execute(new DefaultRedisScript<>(scriptText), new StringRedisSerializer(), new StringRedisSerializer(), keys, argv);
}
```

This says use `StringRedisSerializer` for any value, so when we do - `set a 2`, using `JdkSerializationRedisSerializer`, 2 serialized to something like:

`"\xac\xed\x00\x05sr\x00\x11java.lang.Integer\x12\xe2\xa0\xa4\xf7\x81\x878\x02\x00\x01I\x00\x05valuexr\x00\x10java.lang.Number\x86\xac\x95\x1d\x0b\x94\xe0\x8b\x02\x00\x00xp\x00\x00\x00\x02"`

but when we say use `StringRedisSerializer`, 2 is sent as `"2"`, which Redis can easily recognize.

[Official Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis:serializer)